# How can I start/end a C++ Console Application from another C++ Console Application?

Tags: c++, windows

So I made two console applications separately one named *"The Periodic Table"* and the other named *"Search Element"*.

The *"Search Element"* application is the sub part of *"The Periodic Table"* application. So it means that I want to call *"Search Element"* from *"The Periodic Table"* and I want to end all the instances of *"Search Element"* when the user closes *"The Periodic Table"*.

So how can I do that??

#### Additional Information

**Operating System:** Windows 7 32-bit
**Compiler:** Visual C++

Answer (score 2):

- Use `system()` call.

  In your `The Periodic Table` program, call `Search Element` as follows:

  ```
  system("Search Element.exe");
  ```

  Check out [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/182156-running-a-console-application-from-within-another-console-application/page__view__findpost__p__1070336?s=5c43346ff365c0f9baf62606a9a7eb45) for another example.
- Alternatively, you can use `CreateProcess()`. Check out example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/333559/CreateProcess-and-wait-for-result).

Comment: Okay got it but then how do you close all instances of one application as soon as the other closes??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample. Note that there is no error or Ctrl+C handling.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector < PROCESS_INFORMATION > processes_;

    while (true)
    {
        char command_;

        std::cout << "Press n for new Notepad instance or x for Exit\n";
        std::cin >> command_;

        switch(command_)
        {
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
            {
                std::array<TCHAR, 1024> args_ = {};

                PROCESS_INFORMATION info_;

                STARTUPINFO details_ = {};

                details_.cb = sizeof(details_);

                if(CreateProcess(_T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe"), args_.data(), NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &details_, &info_))
                    processes_.push_back(info_);

                break;
            }

            case 'x':
            case 'X':
            {
                for(auto process_ : processes_)
                {
                    TerminateProcess(process_.hProcess, 0);

                    CloseHandle(process_.hProcess);
                    CloseHandle(process_.hThread);
                }

                processes_.resize(0);
            }

            default:
            {
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cout << "Invalid input";
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }
    }
}
```